# problem with progressbar value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have designed a web browser.except for the progress bar it is working fine.

this is my code:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.ProgressChanged
     ProgressBar1.Maximum = e.MaximumProgress
     ProgressBar1.Value = e.CurrentProgress
End Sub
```

the error reported is progressbar1.value should be between max and min
e.currentprogress = -1 is not possible

Comment: I think we'll need to see the code that calls this - i.e. the code where `e.CurrentProgress` is calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A value of -1 means "download has completed", as documented in the MSDN Library article for the property.  Thus:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.ProgressChanged
  If e.CurrentProgress = -1 Then
     ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
     ProgressBar1.Value = 100
  Else
     ProgressBar1.Maximum = e.MaximumProgress
     ProgressBar1.Value = e.CurrentProgress
  End If
End Sub
```

Or you might want to use -1 to hide the progress bar.