# ProgressBar on WebBrowser Value exception

Tags: vb.net, browser, progress-bar

When I try to load any pages I get an exception that says:

`Value of '1010000' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'`.

Sometimes the number is different but the error is always the same. This is the code I am using for the ProgressBar

```
If e.MaximumProgress = -1 Or e.CurrentProgress = -1 Then Exit Sub
        ToolStripProgressBar2.Maximum = e.MaximumProgress
        ToolStripProgressBar2.Value = e.CurrentProgress
```

Am I doing something wrong? I has alleviate the problem in the past by increasing Value but I can't figure out how to do that now. I tried what it said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175966/problem-with-progressbar-value-in-vb-net) but I still get the same error.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of e.MaximumProgress? If this is bigger than e.CurrentProgress, the error would make sense.

Comment: e.MaximumProgress is 10000. I used to be able to change that value but now I can't figure out how.

Comment: if the value is bigger, you can set the maximum to the CurrentProgress, so the error should not appear

Comment: I used e.CurrentProgress = e.MaximumProgress and it says "Property 'CurrentProgress' is 'ReadOnly'"

Comment: i think he meant when e.CurrentProgress > e.MaximumProgress then make ToolStripProgressBar2.maximum = e.Currentprogress rather than e.Maximumprogress - thus allways assum 100%. This is not a correct show of progress but doesn't usually make much difference to an end user